# Unzip files on Bada os?

Tags: unzip, bada

Did somebody know any easy to modify leightweighted zip class to modify for bada?

In an other thread i read that somebody has modified LiteZip for Bada...

Thx in anticipation

plasticlittle

Answer (score 1):

Try [Wave Compressor](http://www.samsungapps.com/topApps/topAppsDetail.as?productId=000000049480&listYN=Y) from [WaveAccess](http://waveaccessllc.blogspot.com/2010/06/we-have-released-our-product-for-bada.html). I use it on my Wave 2 (Bada 1.2). It handles Zip and Bzip2. options exist for 7z and RAR, but are greyed out. Not open-source though.

Comment: You might want to check that link.  Not seeing anything there about bada or compression libs.

Comment: @cHao: Thanks for the note. The links have been cleaned up to be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

use lite ftp   you can download it from getjar